# An Array's filter method of JavaScript is not working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web, internet-explorer-7

I have a `jQuery` plugin used in the web-application which is working well in **IE 10** **and 11**. But it failed in **IE 7**.
When I investigate I came to know that the value of  `filter` method is `undefined`. 
The line of code fails is as follow:

```
if (splitters.filter(Boolean).length === 0) {
```

I am using `jQuery 1.8.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JavaScript **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method , it's only supported in [IE 9+ as per the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility)

---

[Check polyfill option from MDN for older browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill).

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t) {
        var val = t[i];

        // NOTE: Technically this should Object.defineProperty at
        //       the next index, as push can be affected by
        //       properties on Object.prototype and Array.prototype.
        //       But that method's new, and collisions should be
        //       rare, so use the more-compatible alternative.
        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t)) {
          res.push(val);
        }
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```